# Copying a file and saving it in another format

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am copying a file from sample.csv to new.csv. After I copied I need to open new.csv and save it as new.xls with worksheet name "Newsheet". I copied successfully but couldn't move on to open it/save it.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")      
    Dim ioLine As String
    Dim ioLines As String      
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine     
    ioLines = "ID,Name,Number,Amount"
    ioLines &= vbCrLf & ioLine 
    While Not ioLine = ""         
        ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine         
        ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine      
    End While     
    Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")     
    ioWriter.WriteLine(ioLines)     
    ioFile.Close()     
    ioWriter.Close()
```

Comment: You know there's more to an xls/xlsx file than that right? You can't just copy a csv and wave a wand \*poof\* it becomes xls... You will either need automation of Excel, or a library capable of writing Excel files

Comment: -1 for the same reason as provided by Marc Gravell.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import a csv into Exel and you can use excel you can use the folowing code with modifications of course.  As you can see I just recorded a macro.  However I have used macro recording to give me a stub of much more complicated office automation Tasks.  As long as you have the excel library all you need to do is add a reference to it open the app and then pull the code you need from below.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;H:\My Documents\InCps.TXT" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "InCps"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting from basic text to Excel requires a little more work than a file extension change.

I'd take a look at the [NPOI](http://code.google.com/p/npoi/) library, which allows you to easily create Excel documents (as well as other types) and is open source. It is easy to use and you should be able to get a working solution done fast.